# Image hide on checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox

At the start checkboxes are checked and images are shown below. When checkbox in not selected the image hides, if checkbox is selected again the image is shows again.

```
<form action=""> 
 <div> 
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /> House <br /> 
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /> Car <br /> 
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /> Tree <br /> 
  </div> 
</form> 
<p> 
 <img src="house.jpg" alt="House" /> 
 <img src="car.jpg" alt="Car" /> 
 <img src="tree.jpg" alt="Tree" /> 
</p> <script type="text/javascript"> 
<!-- function selectImage(checkbox) { var counter = 0 for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; ++i) { if (checkbox[i].checked) ++stevec } return counter } 
//--> </script>
```

Comment: <form action="">
   <div>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /> House <br />
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /> Car <br />
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /> Tree <br />
   </div>
</form>

<p>
   <img src="house.jpg" alt="House" />
   <img src="car.jpg" alt="Car" />
   <img src="tree.jpg" alt="Tree" />
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

function selectImage(checkbox)
{
   var counter = 0
   for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; ++i) {
     if (checkbox[i].checked) ++stevec
   }
   return counter
 }

   
 
 
//-->
</script>

Comment: You should add more detail, what have you tried etc. [This Stack Overflow Guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) will also probably be a great help for future questions. The code in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539139/change-get-check-state-of-checkbox) includes adding functionality to the `onclick` event, this should be sufficient for what you need to do.

Comment: Please include your code **in your question**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input[type="checkbox"] ~ img { display: none; }
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ img { display: inline; }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/89av9/)

Comment: @user3507447 Why use JavaScript if you can do it with CSS?