# need a javascript function that reads dynamic check box id on jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

i have included a dynamic checkbox using `rs.getstring`. i need to know which checkbox is checked.

```
<th>
  <input type="checkbox" name="chkSingle_<%=counter %>" id ="chkSingle_<%= counter%>" value="<%=rs.getInt(11)%>">
</th>
```

Comment: Check the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5539186/3639582

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the value of checked checkbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599666/get-the-value-of-checked-checkbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function getCheckedItems(checkboxName) {
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="'+checkboxName+'"]:checked'), values = [];
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(checkboxes, function(el) {
        values.push(el.value);
    });
    return values;
}
```

You can call this function and pass the name of the checkbox, you can dynamically bind the onclick function to the button and provide the dynamic name you created while creating the checkbox.

Edited

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkSingle" id ="chkSingle1" value="value1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkSingle" id ="chkSingle2" value="value2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkSingle" id ="chkSingle3" value="value3">
    <button onclick="alert(getCheckedItems('chkSingle'))">Click</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getCheckedItems(checkboxName) {
            var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="'+checkboxName+'"]:checked'), values = [];
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(checkboxes, function(el) {
            values.push(el.value);
            });
            return values;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Edited 2:

Try this method too.

```
function getCheckedItems(checkboxName) {
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(checkboxName);
                var selected = [];
                for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) 
                {
                    if (checkboxes[i].checked) 
                    {
                         selected.push(checkboxes[i].value);
                }
         }
       return selected;
    }
```

***This edit has nothing to do with the question. This edit is on asker's request***

When you are dynamically adding checkboxes, do this:

```
//this is your function I assume.
function toCreateCheckBoxesDynamically()
{
    create checkboxes dynamically;
    attach an attribute as onclick="function WhichTakesCheckedValuesAndAttachValuesToHiddenFields('dynamicallyCreatedCheckBoxName')" to the button.

                                        OR

    //bind a click event to the button and call this function "function WhichTakesCheckedValuesAndAttachValuesToHiddenFields('dynamicallyCreatedCheckBoxName')"
    document.getElementById("yourButton").addEventListener("click", function()
    {
          whichTakesCheckedValuesAndAttachValuesToHiddenFields('dynamicallyCreatedCheckBoxName');
    });
}

// this is the function which you call on button click while submitting the form
function whichTakesCheckedValuesAndAttachValuesToHiddenFields(checkboxName)
{
     var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(checkboxName);
            var selected = "";
            for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) 
            {
                if (checkboxes[i].checked) 
                {
                      if(selected == "" || selected == 'undefined')
                             selected = checkboxes[i].value;
                      else
                             selected = selected +","+ checkboxes[i].value;
                }
        }

    document.getElementById("hiddenFieldName").value = selected ;// the stored value is comma separated string so retrieve it on the server by using split method which will give you string array and then do your further work.
    document.getElementById("yourFormName").submit(); // submit this form
}
```

hidden field syntax:

```
<input type=hidden name="yourHiddenFieldName" value="">// inside your form in html
```

***OR one more tip***

you can also save the dynamically created checkbox name in the hidden field in the form and after submitting get those checked values on the basis of that hidden field value as

```
String checkBoxName = request.getParameter('hiddenFieldName');
```

and then get all checkedBoxes values as

```
String checkedboxes[] = request.getParameterValues(checkBoxName);
```

Doing this you will get values of all checked boxes on the server side.

Comment: @AmanArora check the edited answer, have provided a simple demo.

Comment: document.querySelectorAll   this gives an error that says document doesn't support this property. Can you do it using document.getelementbyid

Comment: have you included this tag at the very start of your document "<!DOCTYPE html>"

Comment: how can we do it using id when there are multiple checkboxes? because ids are unique.

Comment: @AmanArora, I edited my answer to add new method, please check it.

Comment: Can you tell me how to get the result from this function and use that result as input parameter to call a servlet

Comment: @AmanArora when you are submitting your form, call this method and save the value returned by this function in a hidden field in the form, so that when your form is submitted it will be available to servlet. On the servlet side just take down the value as request.getParameter("hiddenFieldName").

Comment: @AmanArora if you are satisfied with the answer for your main question , then you can accept the answer.

Comment: i am a beginner can you please tell me the exact syntax for how could i store the function value.....thanks in advance

Comment: Do one thing, call a function on your button click, in that function set the checkbox value in a hidden field which is in your form, and then submit your form from javascript as formname.submit(); , i will show you syntax in evening, m out currently, commented through mobile.

Comment: @AmanArora I have edited and tried to explain what you can do. If any problem , please let me know.

Comment: @AmanArora you can also save the dynamically created checkbox name in the hidden field in the form and after submitting get those checked values on the basis of that hidden field value as String checkBoxName = request.getParameter('hiddenFieldName'); and then get all checkedBoxes values as String checkedzboxed[] = request.getParameterValues(checkBoxName); Doing this you will get values of all checked boxes on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$("input:checked[name^='chkSingle_']")` to get all checkboxes that are selected.

Comment: he has tagged only javascript, not jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
var ids = [],
    cbx = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

for (i = 0, l = cbx.length; i < l; i++) {
       ids.push(cbx[i].id);
}

console.log(ids);
```

If you want anymore help, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G44hH/1/) is available