# Why is this checkbox missing the "checked" property?

Tags: javascript, dom, properties

In a component I'm writing I want to examine the "checked" property of an  element. Unfortunately, it appears that the element doesn't contain the "checked" property, at least not the way I set things up.

Here's the JS snippet:

```
var submenus  = document.querySelectorAll( ".hbm-panel-item-label" );
for ( var label of submenus ) {
  // console.log( "label.for = " + label.getAttribute( "for" ) );

  label.addEventListener( "click", function() {
    var label_for = this.getAttribute( "for" ); 
    // console.log( label_for + " was clicked." );

    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll( ".hbm-panel-item-checkbox" );
    for ( var cb of checkboxes ) {
      console.debug( cb );

      if ( cb.getAttribute( "name" ) === label_for ) {
        console.log( label_for + " has attribute 'checked': " + cb.hasAttribute( "checked" ) );
        console.log( label_for + " is " + cb.getAttribute( "checked" ) );  
      }
    }
  });
}
```

...and here's the result:

[image: Firefox console output]

When I open the properties for that element, I do see a checked property with a value of "false":

[image]

Apologies in advance, I'm a JS rookie. I get the feeling this is something simple. I also get the feeling that if I used jQuery this would take about three lines of code...

Comment: Maybe checkbox.checked will work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539139/change-get-check-state-of-checkbox#5539186

Comment: You said it in your title. It is a "property", not an "attribute"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A property is in the DOM, an attribute is in the HTML that is parsed into the DOM.
The HTML for the checkbox has no attribute 'checked', but the checkbox has a property 'checked'.
You'll probably just need to check

```
cb.checked
```

instead of looking for the attribute.

Comment: That's it. Working too hard. Thanks.