# How to reset HTML form checkbox values after Back/Forward button click in browser?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Everything works fine unless a user clicks back/forward. At which point the checkbox values do not reset to previous state.

I have a HTML form (with php) to input search criteria with a submit button to execute a search. I used *hidden* input fields for the two checkboxes to retain the value after the submit executes. That looks like this:

```
search.php

          <?php
              $search = [];
              $search['keyword'] =  $_GET['keyword'] ?? '';
              $search['startDateRange'] =  $_GET['startDateRange'] ?? '';
              $search['endDateRange'] =  $_GET['endDateRange'] ?? '';
              $search['requestedBy'] =  $_GET['requestedBy'] ?? '';

              if (isset($_GET['openStatus'])) {
                $search['openStatus'] = $_GET['openStatus'];
              } else {
                $search['openStatus'] = "on";
              }

              if (isset($_GET['closedStatus'])) {
                $search['closedStatus'] = $_GET['closedStatus'];
              } else {
                $search['closedStatus'] = "on";
              }
          ?>

          <form action="search.php" autocomplete="off" id="searchCriteria">
                
                <label>Keyword</label>
                <input type="text" autocomplete="off" value = "<?php echo $search['keyword']; ?>" name="keyword" id="keyword" />
                <br>
                <label>Request Date</label>
                <input type="date" value = "<?php echo $search['startDateRange']; ?>" name="startDateRange" id="startDateRange" />
                <label>to</label>
                <input type="date" value = "<?php echo $search['endDateRange']; ?>" name="endDateRange" id="endDateRange"/>
                <br>
                <label>Requested By</label>
                <input type="text" value = "<?php echo $search['requestedBy']; ?>" name="requestedBy" 
                id="requestedBy"/>
                <br>

                <input type="hidden" name="openStatus" value="off" >
                <input type="checkbox" value = "on" id="openStatus" name="openStatus" <?php echo $search['openStatus']=="on" ? 'checked' : ''; ?>/>
                <label>include Open Requests</label>
                <br>

                <input type="hidden"  name="closedStatus" value="off" >
                <input type="checkbox"  value = "on" id="closedStatus" name="closedStatus" <?php echo $search['closedStatus']=="on" ? 'checked' : ''; ?>/>
                <label>include Completed Requests</label>
                <br>
                
                <input type="submit" value="Refine Search">
                
                <button onclick="location.href='index.php'" type="button">
                Back to Requests</button>
                
              
            </form>
```

This works fine until the user hits the back button. To fix this problem I added the following javascript:

```
<script>
  //added to fix back/forward button cache problem
  window.addEventListener("pageshow", () => {
     //these four work
     document.getElementById("keyword").value = "<?php echo $search['keyword']; ?>";
     document.getElementById("startDateRange").value = "<?php echo $search['startDateRange']; ?>";
     document.getElementById("endDateRange").value = "<?php echo $search['endDateRange']; ?>";
     document.getElementById("requestedBy").value = "<?php echo $search['requestedBy']; ?>";

     //these two don't work
     document.getElementById("openStatus").value = "<?php echo $search['openStatus']; ?>";
     document.getElementById("closedStatus").value = "<?php echo $search['closedStatus']; ?>";
  >";
  });
</script>
```

This javascript properly reset the text type input values, but doesn't reset the checkbox fields. I assume the problem lies in my use of the *hidden* input fields, but it's unclear to me how to fix it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change/Get check state of CheckBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539139/change-get-check-state-of-checkbox)

Comment: Don't change the `value` of checkboxes, you change the `checked` attribute to exist or not. See link above.

Comment: value vs checked was my problem. Thanks!