# Make a checkbox look like a button CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I think what I am trying to achieve can be done in a simpler manner. However I have little JS experience and none in the way of CSS. So I’m utilizing prebuilt CSS and JS code and subtlety modifying it. So I will explain my end goal and see if what I currently have is acceptable.

1. A top menu on the webpage that has push buttons and checkboxes that all visually look the same
2. I would like checkboxes to look like buttons, e.g. no checkbox only the label.
3. I would like for the checkbox to still retain its functionality as a checkbox given the JS code it is calling
4. Is the way I’m calling the JS code through the button and checkbox correct or too complicated?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deaconf19/7E8Ea/6/)

---

```
<li><a title="Zoom to U.S" input type="button" name="US" onclick="US();"><span>Zoom to U.S.</span></a></li>  
<li><a title="Test 1 KML"><input type="checkbox" id="kml-red-check" name="kml-red-check" onclick="toggleKml("red");"><span>Test 1 KML</span></a></li>
```

Comment: Pair the checkbox with a label, hide the checkbox and style the label making it look like a button

Comment: Whenever I add the '/**
 `* Start by hiding the checkboxes
 */
input[type=checkbox] {
 visibility: hidden;
}`
it stops working

Comment: I'd like to add that you should generally never use `onclick` on a checkbox or radiobutton since this doesn't cover other methods of toggling (e.g. via keyboard or clicking on a label). Use `onchange` instead. This is also likely the reason why it doesn't work when you hide the checkbox.

Comment: I changed the `onclick` to `onchange` and I still exhibit the same results when I hide the checkbox via CSS

Comment: Is there a specific reason you have input elements inside an a tag?

Comment: I am piecing together information to get results. What should I do to correct this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```css
.hidden {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox]+label {
  color: #ccc;
  font-style: italic;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+label {
  color: #f00;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="hidden" name="cb" id="cb">
<label for="cb">text</label>
```

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/

Won't work on lt IE9 though.

edit: Following your markup it should be something like this:

```
<ul>
<li><input id="cb1" name="cb1-name" type="checkbox" onkeypress="setTimeout('checkIt(\'cb1\')',100);"><label for="cb1" onclick="setTimeout('checkIt(\'cb1\')',100);">text 1</label></li>
<li><input id="cb2" name="cb2-name" type="checkbox" onkeypress="setTimeout('checkIt(\'cb2\')',100);"><label for="cb2" onclick="setTimeout('checkIt(\'cb2\')',100);">text 2</label></li>
</ul>
```

And then check if the checkbox is checked or not in your function.
[onchange / onclick in a checkbox doesn't work in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117716/onchange-onclick-in-a-checkbox-doesnt-work-in-ie)

edited again: changed NAME attribute so you won't end up having problems further along the line. And added a little workaround for the unresponsive, though ultimately desired, onchange functionality in IE8. Eventually you should add a timer to your function, rather than inline.

```
function checkIt(e){
    if(document.getElementById(e).checked){
    alert('checked');
    } else {
    alert('unchecked');
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. I am not worried about the IE9 version since I have a generic CSS that I am loading for IE9 and below thanks.

Comment: @user2704746 O, it'll work in IE9. Just not any version up untill IE9.

Comment: I tested earlier I saw that thank it is working perfect and you aided me by adding the color option as well. Thanks again

Answer (score 8):

It is not possible to change the appearence of a checkbox so radically using CSS.

What you CAN do though, is style a label element enough to make it look like a button. Due to the nature of the label element, clicking it will toggle the state of the checkbox keeping your functionality intact.

Here is how to do it

**Markup**

```
<li>
    <label for="kml-red-check">I am a button!</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="kml-red-check" name="kml-red-check" onchange="toggleKml("red");">
</li>
```

Note that I've changed the `onclick` handler to `onchange` since now it is impossible to click the checkbox itself. Its value changes though when you click on the label

**Styling**

```
label[for="kml-red-check"]{
   //Your CSS goes that makes the label look like a button goes here
}
#kml-red-check{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: The CSS I'm using is downloaded as shown in my JSFiddle. I think the entrie code makes the button I'm not sure.

Comment: In your fiddle I don't see you use the `for` attribute of the `label` field. The `for` needs to contain the `id` of the checkbox you want to link the label with...

Comment: I'm running it on my WAMP server and making changes on there since this code is paired with a large set of JS code

Comment: See this Working Example :[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rbHXX/2/).this will be useful to you

Comment: Please read the examples written in the answers carefully. The `for` attribute is completely necessary in the labels, and I don't see it anywhere in your code. I'll just leave it here :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.abc" ng-change="vm.go()"/>
  <span>this is button add some css to lokking like a button</span>
</label>
```

this will work like button , if you don't want to show checkbox use this

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.abc" ng-change=vm.go()" hidden=''/>
  <span>this is button add some css to lokking like a button</span>
</label>
```

check it out here https://jsfiddle.net/h0ntpwqk/2/