# spring tag form:checkbox onchange not working in IE

Tags: java, javascript, spring, internet-explorer-8, jsp-tags

The following code is not working in IE8 using spring form tag.

```
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<script type="javascript/text">
function sampleFunction(){
   alert('Hello World');
}
</script>

<form:checkbox path="${path}" onchange="sampleFunction()" />
```

Is this the way it is supposed to work? 
Am I missing any understanding about onchange event?

Comment: I would use `onclick` for checkboxes. (Not sure about IE8, but I have a vague memory that some browsers won't trigger an `onchange` for checkboxes until they lose focus, like with text inputs.)

Comment: This has nothing to do with spring nor its form tags. It has all to do with IE8. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117716/onchange-onclick-in-a-checkbox-doesnt-work-in-ie

Comment: Ok. got it, using now onclick instead of onchange. Thanks.