# Trouble sending argument to a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I write a function to calcluate the price of some books (that are selected in a list) 
but It doesn't work correctly.

```
function priceCal(bookid,price){    
   if (document.getElementById(bookid).checked) {
        document.getElementById('price').innerHTML=parseInt(document.getElementById("price").innerHTML)+price;
   }
}
```

I call it for examle in one book like this:

```
<input 
  type="checkbox" 
  name="bookList" 
  value="book3" 
  id="bookList_3"  
  onChange="priceCal('bookList_3','50');"
>
```

But it doesn't do anything! What's wrong in sending arguments?! The price is a `<p>` tag with 0 value (for default)

Comment: Nothing's wrong with it. You should send `50` as a number instead of a string but other than that it's fine. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/C7zWy/)

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers are only fireing the `change` event when the input loses focus. Use the `click` event instead. Also to make sure your code works as expected, always pass the `radix` param to the `parseInt` function (it's not 10 by default in all browsers).

You should also avoid passing `price` as a string. Just pass it as a number.

```
var someNum = parseInt('888', 10);
```

Comment: @FelixKling Not in all browsers.

Comment: Which ones are those?

Comment: @FelixKling You are right, it gets fired but only when the input loses focus. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117716/onchange-onclick-in-a-checkbox-doesnt-work-in-ie

Answer (score 0):

Change events only fire if you edit something in input and then blur it, or press enter. Put a console.log at the beginning of your function to check if it is getting to the function at all. Otherwise you can listen to a keydown or blur event, etc.

Comment: I log it ... and also I check onClick ... but it dosen't work yet :(